# Adding a filter seems to produce more results

Tags: elasticsearch

Weird situation involving adding filters to an existing bool query.

This query here, brings up exactly one result, one from the "pages" index. 
The "documents" index, predictably on our side, has zilch for results for this query.

This makes sense. This version of the query works just fine.

```
{
  "index": "pages"
}
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "title_exact": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "versions",
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                      "versions.page_content"
                    ],
                    "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "index": "documents"
}
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "title_exact": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "product.versions",
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                      "versions.page_content"
                    ],
                    "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, users have the ability to add a filter to an existing query, in this case that's a product.

This is the query that gets sent.

```
{
  "index": "pages"
}
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "title_exact": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "versions",
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                      "versions.page_content"
                    ],
                    "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "product_id": "a2c2c792-84ac-11e8-b4c6-005056a40c60"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "index": "documents"
}
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "title_exact": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "product.versions",
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                      "versions.page_content"
                    ],
                    "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "product.id": "a2c2c792-84ac-11e8-b4c6-005056a40c60"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here, is that while the "pages" index still produces the one result as desired, the "documents" index now suddenly matches against every record that has that product id in it and bumps up the results.

both "filter" and "must" do the same thing in this scenario.

Honestly, it should be producing the exact same result as the previous query.  Filters should only be reducing result sets, not increasing them.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Add [minimum-should-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) to your `bool` query, to tell the query returns documents only when at least `X` number of `should` clauses are match. It seems like the default value is `0`, that's why results are based on `filter` query, and `should` is just assigning `scoring`.

Query after adding `minimum-should-match`:

```
{
  "index": "documents"
}
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "title_exact": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "product.versions",
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                      "versions.page_content"
                    ],
                    "query": "\"this is a test search phrase\""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "product.id": "a2c2c792-84ac-11e8-b4c6-005056a40c60"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Problem

A brief explanation here:

- `filter` - Just filter documents, nothing to do with `scoring`
- `should` - Contribute to `scoring` if match. However [minimum-should-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) will change how documents should be returned.
- `must` - Filter documents and contribute to `scoring`

[Bool query doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html)

In your second `document` query, the total hits is based on the `filter` clause, and `should` clause will only assign `scoring` to the matched documents, it doesn't reduce results because of [minimum-should-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) is (probably default to) `0`

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow when I'm back at the office, thank you.  I will say though that in response to the explanation, providing "must" instead if "filter" produced the same results.  I had briefly considered just doing this approach when I first saw the issue manifest itself, but figured I'd try to figure out if there was just something wrong with my query first.  Thank you so much for taking the time :)

Comment: Yes I overlooked the `must` thing, would be great if you will share the update!